Error in pip command - directory not installable
I am new to python and trying to setup using this-
https://github.com/facebookresearch/CodeGen/blob/main/install_env.sh
in google collab notebook.
But, it is throwing error in the below line:
pip install -v --disable-pip-version-check --no-cache-dir --global-option="--cpp_ext" --global-option="--cuda_ext" ./

I tried changing the last parameter to /bin but still doesn't work.
Can someone please help.
Below is the error:
Using pip 24.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip (python 3.10)
ERROR: Directory './' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.
/bin/bash: line 1: go: command not found


Sounds like a question for https://github.com/facebookresearch/CodeGen/issues first, not Stackoverflow first? If the instructions of some open source project don't work, let the maintainers know so they can fix the docs.

In the shell script you pointed there are these commands before pip install ./:
git clone https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex
cd apex

The cloned repository is pip-installable, it has all necessary files: pyproject.toml and setup.py so the command pip install ./ works.
You need to repeat all steps from the shell script, esp. to clone the NVIDIA/apex repository.
